# Undo TextMate command ctrl+shift+alt+p

Tags: textmate

I was going to try out a keyboard shortcut for doing a preview of CSS in TextMate. By mistake I pushed the wrong key combination(ctrl+shift+alt+p) which displayed a little window in the CSS document with four options to choose from. The options were:

1. Perl
2. Plain text
3. Property List
4. Python

I chose one of the options to see what it was and it changed the syntax highlighting of the document. The problem is now that I cant seem to undo this. Despite the theme I choose in TextMate it does not affect the highlighting. This is very annoying and I have searched every where for an answer but cant find one. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that this does not work, but just to be clear, you need to select the language from the menu at the window bottom. Or just hit ⌃⌥⇧P again and select *Plain Text*.

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind that the *theme* in the preferences just changes the general colors used throughout TextMate for whatever *language* you're using. I guess you could have also hit ⌃⌥⇧C and select *CSS* again.